# слова спочивати і почивати чи є різниця

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, різниця-між-словами, синоніми, правопис

Чи є нюанси тлумачення слів *спочивати* та *почивати*. Обидва перекладаються як *спати*, *відпочивати*, *померти*.

> Розпрягайте, хлопцi, коней,
> Тай лягайте спочивать

Як зрозуміти, коли мається на увазі *спати*,  а коли *відпочивати*?

Або [*в зимку земля*] *почиває* чи *спочиває*, як правильніше, якщо треба передати, що [*вона*] *відпочиває*, чи і так і так можна?

Answer (score -1):

#### Чи є нюанси тлумачення слів *спочивати* та *почивати*.

> <sup>*Словник української мови: в 11 томах*</sup>
>
> [СПОЧИВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/spochyvaty), аю, аєш, *недоконаний вид*, *[…]*
>
> 1. Те саме, що [відпочивати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidpochyvaty).
> 2. Те саме, що [спати](http://sum.in.ua/s/spaty).
> 3. *переносне значення*, *урочисто* Бути мертвим, лежати в могилі.
>
> [ПОЧИВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pochyvaty), аю, аєш, *недоконаний вид*, *[…]*
>
> 1. Спати, впадати в сон.
> 2. *тільки недоконаний вид*, *застаріле*. Покоїтися, лежати в труні, в могилі, спочивати вічним сном (про прах, тіло).

Різниці загалом немає, хіба що *почивати* не має в собі *відпочивати*, хоча, як на мене, так можна вживати. Пак згаданий словник має згадане в іншому відповіді *спочивати*, і *почивати* [*на лаврах*].

Але можна зробити певний висновок, же *спочивати* — частковий покій, а *почивати* — повний. Порівняй з *спокійний* і [*покійний*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokijnyj), де друге може мати значення *спокійний*, але наразі вживається переважно як *мертвий*.

#### Коли мається на увазі *спати*, а коли *відпочивати*?

З контексту. Краще сприймайте слово *як бути в стані спокою*. Те саме з *відпочивати* і *спати*, котрі теж можуть мати значення *бути мертвим*.

Comment: Зробіть будь ласка словотвірний розбір слова, щоб я міг прибрати свою відповідь

Comment: Спочити, відпочити, перепочити і почити - не одне й те саме.